# Coq : Admit assert

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

Is there a way to admit asserts in Coq ?

Suppose I have a theorem like this:

```
Theorem test : forall m n : nat,
    m * n = n * m.
Proof.
  intros n m.
  assert (H1: m + m * n = m * S n). { Admitted. }
Abort.
```

The above assert doesn't seem to work for me.

The error I receive is:

```
Error: No focused proof (No proof-editing in progress).
```

What I want is something like `undefined` in Haskell. Baiscally, I will come back to this later and prove it. Is there something like that in Coq to achieve it ?

Comment: In general the tactic `admit` (lower-case first letter) admits the current subgoal. Thus, `assert <your assertion>. admit.` or `asset <your assertion>; admit.` should work in your case.

Comment: @ichistmeinname Thanks, that works. Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general the tactic `admit` (lower-case first letter) admits the current subgoal. Thus `assert <your assertion>. admit.` should work in your case.

Or in its full glory as follows.

```
Theorem test : forall m n : nat,
  m * n = n * m.
Proof.
  intros n m.
  assert (H1: m + m * n = m * S n). admit.
Abort.
```

Edit: The version with `;` is nonsense, because you do not want to admit all subgoals.

Comment: Also, as of Coq 8.5 (I think not earlier), any proof script with `admit` in it needs to be ended with `Admitted.` instead of `Qed.`/`Defined.` if you want to save the result.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Ending it with `Qed` works for me in version `8.4pl4`.

Comment: ANother syntax is ``assert (H1: m + m * n = m * S n) by admit.``